# odoo 8 imported customer invoices can not be validated?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

i have a project to make integration between odoo 8 and another system , my scope was insert all the customers codes from the other system into odoo database witch i already done without any problems , but when i try to insert customer invoices into odoo i face a problem , 
i had already insert all the invoices in 2 tables :
1. account_invoice (includes the master data)
2. account_invoice_line (includes the details)
now i can view all the invoices in odoo but **WHEN I TRY TO VALIDATE THE INVOICES** system do nothing (no error messages , or hangups) 
do i miss any thing ?
thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the code? if you are using default odoo account module then I guess your problem is either missing data or the validate function in account module is not working properly.